# Pyspark : How to escape backslash ( \ ) in input file

Tags: python, pyspark

I am loading a csv file into postgresql using pyspark. I have a record in the input file which looks like below -

```
Id,dept,city,name,country,state
1234,ABC,dallas,markhenry\,USA,texas
```

When I load it into the postgresql database then it gets loaded like this which is not correct -

```
Id   | dept| city   | name          | country | state
1234 | ABC | dallas | markhenry,USA | texas   | null
```

correct output in postgresdb should be -

```
Id   | dept| city   | name          | country | state
1234 | ABC | dallas | markhenry     |   USA   | texas
```

I am reading the file like below -

```
input_df = spark.read.format("csv").option("quote", "\"").option("escape", "\"").option("header", 
"true").load(filepath)
```

Is there a way I can modify my code to handle the backslash () coming in the data. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you just want to skip the character, right?

Comment: Yes. It should read and parse the file correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the "quote" option is to specify a quote character, which wraps entire column values. Not sure if that is needed here, but you can use the `regexp_replace` function to remove specific characters (just select everything else as-is and modify the `name` column this way).

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").csv(filepath)
df2 = df.select(col("Id"), col("dept"), col("city"), regexp_replace(col("name"), "\\\\", "").alias("name"), col("country"), col("state"))
df2.show(4, False)
```

Output:

```
+----+----+------+---------+-------+-----+
|Id  |dept|city  |name     |country|state|
+----+----+------+---------+-------+-----+
|1234|ABC |dallas|markhenry|USA    |texas|
+----+----+------+---------+-------+-----+
```